# PanGestureRecognizer does not work in contentview

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Hi I want to do that when a user swipes content to view it went down and up, but unfortunately, my code doesn't work, please help. I tried to use PanGestureRecognizer, but I do not know but I don't know if I'm doing it right

```
     <controls:CustomFrame CornerRadius="25,25,0,0" Margin="0" Padding="10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ScrollView>
    <AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="Silver" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,1">
        <StackLayout x:Name="bottomDrawer" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,1.00,0.9,0.04" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="PanGestureHandler" />
            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding MyPins}"  x:Name="ListPlaces"    
                   SelectionMode="None">
                      SOMETHING
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </controls:CustomFrame>
```

COde behind

```
   public partial class PlacesList : ContentView, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public List<CustomPin> myPins { get; set; }
        public List<CustomPin> MyPins { get => myPins; set { myPins = value; OnPropertyChanged("MyPins"); } }
        public ICommand CallPlace { get; set; }

        double? layoutHeight;
        double layoutBoundsHeight;
        int direction;
        const double layoutPropHeightMax = 0.75;
        const double layoutPropHeightMin = 0.04;
        void PanGestureHandler(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            layoutHeight = layoutHeight ?? ((sender as StackLayout).Parent as AbsoluteLayout).Height;
            switch (e.StatusType)
            {
                case GestureStatus.Started:
                    layoutBoundsHeight = AbsoluteLayout.GetLayoutBounds(sender as StackLayout).Height;
                    break;
                case GestureStatus.Running:
                    direction = e.TotalY < 0 ? 1 : -1;
                    break;
                case GestureStatus.Completed:
                    if (direction > 0) // snap to max/min, you could use an animation....
                    {
                        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(bottomDrawer, new Rectangle(0.5, 1.00, 0.9, layoutPropHeightMax));
                      //  swipeLabel.Text = "Swipe me down";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(bottomDrawer, new Rectangle(0.5, 1.00, 0.9, layoutPropHeightMin));
                       // swipeLabel.Text = "Swipe me up";
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        public PlacesList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext =  this;
```

Comment: Both Scrollview and CollectionView can achieve the move up/down contentview function and there is no need to use a PanGestureRecognizer on a contentView. Tell us what you want to do with more detailed information and then we can help better.

Comment: I want to hide a content view when user swap down and show content view on the page when user swap up

Comment: To hide/show a contentView, you can set the IsVisible property of the contentView to false/true in the swap down/down event.

Comment: Can you give me example please?I am about how to write this event

Comment: Is [draganddropgesture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/workingwithgestures-draganddropgesture/) you want? You want to move the control or swipe the page to hide the view?

Comment: this project doesn't start, so I want to swipe down to hide my contentview on the page

Comment: Sorry.I see only now.T9(( Not swap but swipe

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [swipe gesture recognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/swipe) to hide/show content view when swiping on view:

```
<ContentPage.Content>

    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightYellow">
        <!-- Place new controls here -->

        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

            <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Down" Swiped="SwipeGestureRecognizer_Swiped"/>
            <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Up" Swiped="SwipeGestureRecognizer_Swiped"/>

        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

        <Label x:Name="myLabel" Text="Swipe down to hide me, swipe up to show me" BackgroundColor="Green"
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

    </StackLayout>
    
</ContentPage.Content>
```

In code behind:

```
private void SwipeGestureRecognizer_Swiped(object sender, SwipedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Direction)
    {
        case SwipeDirection.Left:
            // Handle the swipe
            break;
        case SwipeDirection.Right:
            // Handle the swipe
            break;
        case SwipeDirection.Up:
            // Handle the swipe
            myLabel.IsVisible = true;
            break;
        case SwipeDirection.Down:
            // Handle the swipe
            myLabel.IsVisible = false;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem,that I need a collection view, and <SwipeGestureRecognizer doesn't want to work with collection view

Comment: You can add the stacklayout to header of collectionView. See document here [Display views in the header and footer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#display-views-in-the-header-and-footer).